# Shape of the "act" claim after token exchange in a system context

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, clientid, token-exchange

I am currently implementing an OAuth token exchange STS and am struggling a bit. The standard is defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693
My use case involves a chain of system-to-system calls, triggered by a user (principal) action. I want to make sure that authorization on endpoint levels is done by a mix of scopes and white-listed client_ids. In addition I'd like to keep the customer context.

I see that the token exchange scenario is valid here. The specification gives an example where the resulting token contains the actor to whom access was delegated. However, the specification puts the logical system (aka OAuth client) into the "sub" claim of the nested actor information, as shown here:

```
{
  "aud":"https://service26.example.com",
  "iss":"https://issuer.example.com",
  "exp":1443904100,
  "nbf":1443904000,
  "sub":"user@example.com",
  "act":
  {
    "sub":"https://service16.example.com",
    "act":
    {
      "sub":"https://service77.example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I find this a bit odd. I would expect the "sub" claim to carry an actual subject, if the actor token was a personalized token as well (say, "adminuser"). In my opinion, the system that was conducting the token exchange would send as an actor token a client_credentials token. This does not contain a "sub" claim, but only the "cid" (client_id) claim. This claim should be included in the "act" claim of the resulting token, so I would expect the resulting token to look like this:

```
{
  "aud":"https://service26.example.com",
  "iss":"https://issuer.example.com",
  "exp":1443904100,
  "nbf":1443904000,
  "sub":"user@example.com",
  "cid":"3rd_client_that_conducted_token_exchange",
  "act":
  {
    "cid":"2nd_client_id",
    "act":
    {
      "cid":"initial_client_id"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a required structure for the "act" claim (as far as I see, no). Is there a best practice to follow here? Curious for your thoughts! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `act` claim does not have a standardised structure, the only thing the RFC mentions is that it should consist of any information that would enable you to identify the actor.

Whether the `act` claim should contain information about a user or about a client depends on the architecture of your system, and on which information will be usable or required by your other services. If you have a scenario in which user's privileges are delegated to an admin and you want to have **that** information in the token, you will put the admin's data in the `act.sub` claim. But if you want to point out that one client is delegating privileges to another client, you will have the client id in the `act.sub` claim. The client ID can also be the subject, if the delegation is done between clients not users.

Remember that you can also have impersonation scenario for a token exchange. So, in the resulting token you will not have any information about the actor. E.g. you can have your admin impersonate a user. After performing the token exchange you will issue the user's token, without any information that it is actually the admin user who is handling that token.

You mention that you have a chain of systems between which you want to exchange tokens. I believe that for this scenario the client ID will indeed become the subject for your `act` claim. If I understand correctly you have a situation in which you have a token for user X, issued to be used at API service 1 (the `aud` claim indicates that). Then API service 1 want to gain access to service 2, and needs to exchange the token. It now gets another token where the sub is user X, audience is service 2 and `act.sub` is service 1, as this service now acts as the user and wants to access resources at service 2.

Comment: thanks for your input Michal! Glad to see I wasn't missing a rfc that defines the `act` claim in more detail, I appreciate your explanation.